# Replacing 1 column of CSV from float to char with Python/NumPy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy

Consider the following code:

```
data = np.loadtxt("submission_zca_.csv", dtype=np.float32, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
print "Encoded Data :", data
print "shape", data.shape


for x in xrange(0, data.shape[0]):
    #decode_to_string returns "a","b","c",....
    value = decode_to_string(data[x, 1])
    print "Value", value
    data[x,1]=value
```

This produces the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: G
```

How do I replace the second column of this `CSV` by char/string using `NumPy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy arrays have a fixed dtype. 
So if you use `data = np.loadtxt(..., dtype='np.float32')` then `data` will have a `float32` dtype and you will not be able to assign string values to `data`. For example,

```
In [14]: data = np.random.random((2,3))

In [15]: data[0,1] = 'G'
ValueError: could not convert string to float: G
```

Here are some options:

1. Use `np.genfromtxt` and specify a converter function:

   ```
   data = np.genfromtxt("submission_zca_.csv", dtype=None, delimiter=',', 
                     skiprows=1, converters={1: decode_to_string})
   ```

   This will build a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html). For example, if the CSV contains

   ```
   A,B,C
   1,2,3
   4,5,6
   ```

   then

   ```
   def decode_to_string(x):
       return 'foo'*int(x)
   data = np.genfromtxt("submission_zca_.csv", dtype=None, delimiter=',', 
                        skiprows=1, converters={1: decode_to_string})
   ```

   yields

   ```
   array([(1, 'foofoo', 3), (4, 'foofoofoofoofoo', 6)], 
         dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', 'S15'), ('f2', '<i8')])
   ```
2. Simply use a list of lists:

   ```
   import csv
   data = []
   with open("submission_zca_.csv", 'rb') as f:
       for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
           row = list(map(float, row))
           row[1] = decode_to_string(row[1])
           data.append(row)
   ```
3. Or, you could create a second structured array or array of `object` dtype after using `np.loadtxt`, copy values from `data` into it, and then write the string values into the new array too. But I don't see any advantage to doing it this way over using option 1 or 2.
4. It is possible to *view* the array with a different dtype. In fact, you could
   change an array of dtype `float32` into a structured array with one (or more)
   columns with dtype `S4` (4-byte strings). But the string column(s) would have to
   be exactly 4-bytes in size since `float32` occupies 4 bytes and the size of the
   array can not be changed without resizing (and therefore copying) the array.
   Thus, this option would be of limited value unless you can guarantee that `decode_to_string` returns 4-byte strings.

   ```
   In [35]: data = np.genfromtxt("submission_zca_.csv", dtype=np.float32, delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

   In [36]: data
   Out[36]: 
   array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
          [ 4.,  5.,  6.]], dtype=float32)

   In [37]: data.dtype
   Out[37]: dtype('float32')

   In [51]: data = data.ravel().view([('f0', 'float32'), ('f1', 'S4'), ('f2', 'float32')])

   In [52]: data
   Out[52]: 
   array([(1.0, '\x00\x00\x00@', 3.0), (4.0, '\x00\x00\xa0@', 6.0)], 
         dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', 'S4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
   ```

You could then assign different 4-byte values to the second column this way:

```
    In [53]: data['f1'] = ['fooo', 'barr']

    In [55]: data
    Out[55]: 
    array([(1.0, 'fooo', 3.0), (4.0, 'barr', 6.0)], 
          dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', 'S4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```